# Parse Html with Python and lxml.html

Tags: python, parsing, screen-scraping, lxml

I'm creating a Python scraper at scraperwiki.com. I need to parse a part of a html page that contains the following code:

```
<div class="div_class">
    <h3>I'm a title. Don't touch me</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
        I'm a title. Parse me
            <ul>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        I'm a title. Parse me
        <ul>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        I'm a title. Parse me
        <ul>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        I'm a title. Parse me
        <ul>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
                <li>fdfdsfd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to parse only "I'm a title. Parse me" titles. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
import scraperwiki
import lxml.html
import re 
import datetime
#.......................
raw_string = lxml.html.fromstring(scraperwiki.scrape(url_to_scrape))
raw_html = raw_string.cssselect("div.div_class ul > li")
for item in ras_html
  print(item.text_content())
```

I does work. But it captures **all** the data insile ul. I don't want it, I want to find only "I'm a title. Parse me" in each ul and that's it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of the `lxml` is that you can use both css selectors and xpath to find any element on the page.

In your case, since you have nested `<ul>` lists, it's better to use xpath for navigation:

```
# find every <li> in the <ul> under div with class div_class
raw_html = raw_string.xpath("//div[@class='div_class']/ul/li")
for item in raw_html:
    print(item.text.strip())
```

prints:

```
I'm a title. Parse me
I'm a title. Parse me
I'm a title. Parse me
I'm a title. Parse me
```

Here is the brief explanation of xpath in lxml: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text

Comment: the difference is in `.text` (single element) vs. `.text_content()` (recursive) otherwise `cssselect("div.div_class > ul > li")` also might work.

Comment: Yep, I thought that too. But with css-select all <li> are found, even the inner ones, which is not what was needed.

Comment: @Vladimir: Notice that I use `>` in two places (different from the expression in the question).